# strange behaviour of std::string buffer

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, std

I found strange behavior of `std::string`

I have compiled below code and executing on ubuntu I am getting different output for char buffer and `std::string` buffer.

```
string m_fileName = "test.txt";
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open (m_fileName.c_str(), ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);

string readBuffer="";
string fileContent = "";
char data[2048];
strcpy(data,"");

while(myfile.read((char *)readBuffer.c_str(),13)) {
    strcat(data,readBuffer.c_str());
    fileContent += readBuffer;
}

myfile.close();

QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText(fileContent.c_str());
msgBox.exec();

QMessageBox msgBox1;
msgBox1.setText(data);
msgBox1.exec();
```

`std::string` fileContent display last line only.
char data display whole file content. 
????

Comment: You open myfile for with flags for appending output?  Then wry to read in to `readBuffer` when you don't know that there are 13 characters available for your use at `.c_str()` - what a mess!  Google for "C++ read file into string" and you'll see plenty of examples.

Comment: `(char *)readBuffer.c_str()` That thing is `const` for a reason. Casting isn't some silver bullet. And minor, `data[0] = 0;` is plenty sufficient for setting up a terminated buffer. No need for that `strcpy()`

Answer (score 2):

You're writing to unallocated memory. That's Undefined Behavior, anything can happen.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change some lines of your code as below:

```
string m_fileName = "test.txt";
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open (m_fileName.c_str(), ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);

char readBuffer[24];
string fileContent = "";
char data[2048];
strcpy(data,"");

while(myfile.read(readBuffer,13)) {
      strcat(data,readBuffer);
      fileContent.append(readBuffer);
      fileContent += readBuffer;
}

myfile.close();
```

Comment: This really could use a good paragraph or two describing why stuff needs to be changed.

Comment: Not an answer to the question; it completely ignores the `std::string` buffer.